# DB2: Won't allow parameterize: 'fetch first <X> rows only'

Tags: sql, db2

Although in **Oracle** DB its is allowed to parametrize the number of rows that the query can fetch by adding to the query:

```
select ...
from ...
where ...
and rownum <= @MaximumRecords
```

I can't add similar condition to acuivalent query running in **DB2**:
It is allowed to add:

```
select ... 
from ...
where ...
fetch first 500 rows only
```

(where there is fixed number of rows)
but not:

```
select ... 
from ...   
where ...      
fetch first :1 rows only
```

(:1 == @MaximumRecords)

Is someone aware of a solution/work-around to this problem?

Comment: To Be more accurate - the last queries are made for execution plan and not direct queries.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution. I just ran this query with a tool that gave a 0 default value to @MaximnumRecords
and apperently DB2 doesn't allow to perform:  
**"fetch first 0 rows only"** in any case - that was the problem.