# Parameterize FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY in DB2

Tags: parameters, db2, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to do the following:

```
  select * 
  from table      
  fetch first @param rows only
```

@param is an int.

DB2 would not have it.  I've heard of concatenating it with `||`, but I can't seem to get that to work.

Anyone have experience with this?

(PS I saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621420/db2-wont-allow-parameterize-fetch-first-x-rows-only)) but didn't understand his approach using ':1'.

Comment: Is this a stored procedure?  Are you executing this from a client?  If so, what is the client code written in, and do you have access to it?

Comment: @AJ It's a stored procedure, and I do have access to it.  Can call the sp fine, just can't compile when passing in paramter for fetch first n rows only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
select t.*
from (select r.*, row_number() over() as row_num  
      from table r) as t
where row_num <= @param
```

Comment: I may try that... I just think there should be a way to pass in a parameter to the above query!

Comment: I think (not 100% on this) the reason you can't with the above is the fetch first x rows only syntax is more of an optimization instruction than say a syntax feature for paging. It's instructing DB2 to not perform the usual aggressive prefetch reads thus saving some disk access.

Comment: This may be extremely inefficient with large tables, as you are assigning a row number to every row, then choosing the ones with low numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, where `V_NBR` is your passed in parameter for the number of rows you want:

```
FETCH FIRST ' || DIGITS ( V_NBR ) || '  ROWS ONLY '
```

Comment: Hi @rocket. I'm trying to do your solution on a db2 i-series machine programm. But It doesn't work. can you help me with that?