# Using prepared statement without ROW_NUMBER() and OVER() functions in Db2

Tags: sql, db2, prepared-statement

Let's say I have a table T_SWA.This is my prepared statement.

```
Select version 
From (Select id, version, creator, 
       created_date ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by created_date) cnt 
    From T_SWA 
    Where cnt=3 and id=35);
```

I need to select the 3rd recent version from the T_SWA table. Can anyone suggest a replacement for this query without using `ROW_NUM()` and `OVER()` functiions?

Comment: What is the problem with using ROW_NUMBER to achieve your result?  What are you trying to do differently?

Comment: @Ian: The clients of our company are not allowing us to use it with    OVER() and ROW_NUMBER() functions..That's why we are looking for alternative solutions. So do u have any??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First take the three most recent and then from those three take the first.

```
select id, version, creator, created_date 
from (
    select id, version, creator, created_date 
        from T_SWA
        where id = 35
        order by created_date desc
        fetch first 3 rows only
)
order by created_date
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: When i tried to find the nth record , a datatype mismatch  occurs, possibly at the place where the fetch keyword is being used.Can the Fetch keyword be used to find the nth record??

Comment: No. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751884/paramertize-fetch-first-n-rows-only-in-db2/3774458#3774458 and then the second comment.

Comment: WARNING?: I do not agree. Maybe there is some misunderstanding about what the requested '3rd recent version' does mean. Let's assume there is a version for every day of september 2010. There will be 30 records from 1 till 30 september in the table. The '3rd recent version' would be the version of 28 september. The inner select, ordered by created_date desc, will return september 30, 29 and 28. The outer select, ordered by created_date, will return september 28. Am I missing something?