# Preventing duplicate rows when using UUIDs for primary key

Tags: xml, db2, duplicates, uuid

I've got a database table in DB2 (v9.5) like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE license(key CHAR(16) FOR BIT DATA NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
                     name VARCHAR(32) not null,
                     startDate TIMESTAMP not null, 
                     data XML);
```

(I'm using UUIDs for the primary key as shown in [this guide](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/generating_universally_unique_identifiers_uuid63?lang=en))

My question is one of preventing duplicate entries. My duplicate criteria are as follows:

- Duplicate column values are ok. e.g. The `name` value "Fred" can
  appear more than once in the table
- Duplicate rows (ignoring the `key`) are not ok. i.e. Two rows cannot have identical values for `name` AND `startDate` AND `data`.

The way I see it I have a few options:

1. Use something I've missed in the DB2 configuration to make sure that combinations of column values (i.e. `name` AND `startDate` AND `data`) must be unique within the table
2. I have simply made a poor choice of primary key. Should I instead hash the value of the combined fields into a SHA-1 hash (is this a good/bad choice?) and then use that as the primary key. If so, can I just do a String concatenation of the fields into one long String and use BouncyCastle to do the [heavy-lifting](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/org/bouncycastle/crypto/digests/SHA1Digest.html) for me?
3. Prior to doing an INSERT, search the table for the row I'm about to insert and don't insert it if it exists already. I don't know about the efficiency of this (or even how to do it - my DB2 XML knowledge is a bit lacking at the moment - but that's perhaps worth a separate question).
4. Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a unique constraint. Columns can be part of a unique constraint in DB2 only if they are not nullable. Another problem here is the data column of type XML. A column of type XML cannot be part of a unique constraint.

You can add a unique constraint for columns name and startdate like this:

```
CREATE TABLE license(
    key CHAR(16) FOR BIT DATA NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(32) not null,
    startDate TIMESTAMP not null,
    data XML,
    unique(name, startDate)
);
```

You can add a part of the XML column to the unique constraint. I cannot give an example here, as it depends on the specific content of your xml data. Search for "GENERATE KEY USING xmlpattern" for information on this subject.

Comment: A unique contraint can be made on columns that are nullable;  but you can only have 1 row with a NULL.  Only a primary key constraint requires NOT NULL.

Comment: @Ian Bjorhovde: Again I do not agree with you (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828147/using-prepared-statement-without-row-number-and-over-functions-in-db2/3829806#comment-4070510 ) I tested this on DB2 v9.7 on Linux. If column is nullable DB2 responds with: cannot be a column of a primary key or unique key because it can contain null values.. SQLCODE=-542, SQLSTATE=42831. What DB2 version and OS are you using?

Comment: In case it helps, the columns will always be not null (i.e. I'll always have data)

Comment: @Frans: You can create a unique index on a nullable column, and insert a single NULL value into this column.  Attempting to insert an additional NULL will result in error.  However, you are right, if you actually add a unique constraint the column must be not null.