# using sql variable in fetch statement in db2

Tags: sql, db2, row-number

```
DECLARE N_COUNT integer;
set N_COUNT = (select statement returning a single value)
```

Declaring a variable with integer datatype and setting a variable with a value.

```
select * from table1 fetch first (variable) rows only.
```

Now, I need to use the ncount variable in the select statement. I tried to use the variable but returned with an error. How will be able to achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paramertize Fetch First n Rows Only in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751884/paramertize-fetch-first-n-rows-only-in-db2)

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to assign an integer variable `n_count` a set of integer values? It's not possible. Can you describe the goal in other words using some example with test data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FETCH FIRST ROWS ONLY` is an optimization feature, it does not accept variables.

You will need to use `ROW_NUMER()` filtering:

```
 SELECT * FROM (
 select table1.*,
 row_number() over() as rownum
 from table1 
 ) AS t
 where rownum <= :n_count
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as below.

```
DECLARE @N_COUNT int;
SELECT @N_COUNT = ColumnName FROM TableName Where Condtion
```

**Note:** your query should return only single value of data type integer.